# Corner detection of a simple shape in an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a grayscale and noisy image of a simple shape, such as a square, that has 4 corners, and I want to extract their positions. What corner detector is best suited for this application?

I'm trying to avoid SIFT because I'm looking for a simple detector.

Comment: Can you actually upload an example image so we can have a better idea of what "noisy" is?

Answer (score 2):

in a noiseless case, Canny edge detection would give the highest values to the 
4 corners of the square. 
The question is - how noisy is you image. if it's too noisy you'll need a more complex solution for this problem.

if the image is too noisy, I suggest using houghlines transform (matlab function - houghlines) in order to find 4 lines in the image, and then search for their crossovers to get the four corners of the square.

Comment: it's not too noisy. I used harris detector but i guess there could be better ways to find corners. Corners is what im lookin for not the edges. can you tell me how can i use canny edge detector to find "corners"?

Comment: Canny edge detection is based on the image gradient.
You can calculate the image gradient and choose the 4 pixels with maximal gradient value.
if the image is noiseless - the 4 pixels will be exactly the four corners of the square.

if it has noise, you'll probably need to use a different solution which isn't based solely 
on edge detection techniques, such as the hough lines transform which I suggested earlier.

good luck!